# Wont let be have more then 9 Accordions on a page?

Tags: jquery, accordion

So I have this code and it generates the first 9 of the accordions, however will not go past 9.

```
<script>
    $(function() {
        $('#accordion1,#accordion2,#accordion3,#accordion4,#accordion5,#accordion6,#accordion7,#accordion8,#accordion9,#accordion10,#accordion11,#accordion12,#accordion13,#accordion14,#accordion15,#accordion16,#accordion17,#accordion18,#accordion19,#accordion20').accordion();
    });
</script>
```

Any ideas why? And yes I know the code is a mess and I could do (i++ etc..) but leaving as it is for now :)

Oh yeah sorry :S 
So I have a script that generates the id #1....#20 for the div.

```
<script>    
var i = 01;
$('.accordion').each(function(i){
    $(this).attr('id', 'accordion'+(i+1));
});
</script>";
```

Then on the actual div itself I have

```
<div id='' class='accordion'>
 ..............</div>
```

Thanks James

Comment: You've only posted half your code, where's the HTML that the jQuery operates on?

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to just add a class to all of them and apply the accordion to that class ?

Comment: shouldn't have any problems..here's 20 on one page:  http://jsfiddle.net/RPG8t/ Obviously not tweaked for css but they are all there

Comment: show how your 2 code snippets work together in page. Likely a problem there if not getting results you expect

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you already have a class to all the elements you want, why don't you use that to target the accordions ?

```
$(function() {
    $('.accordion').accordion();
});
```

(*additionally, in you code the `var i = 01;` is useless. You only use the `i` parameter of the function*)

Answer (score 1):

If you already have a `accordion` class on the divs, it would be far easier to call the accordion plugin on them this way:

```
<script>
    $(function() {
        $('.accordion').accordion();
    });
</script>
```